# How can I get the two prices from these JComboBoxes?

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment and it's been going fine but now I'm stuck. We have to make a GUI program that lets you choose 1 dorm plan and 1 meal plan. once you click the calculate button your cost per semester appears in a textfield. I'm having trouble with my ButtonListener. Here's some of what I've gotten done

```
private String[] dormList = { "Lincoln Suites Double: $" + LINCOLN_DOUBLE, "Washington Suites Single: $" + WASHINGTON_SINGLE,
                              "Washington Suites Double: $" + WASHINGTON_DOUBLE, "Washington Suites Triple: $" + WASHINGTON_TRIPLE,
                              "Roosevelt Suites Double: $" + ROOSEVELT_DOUBLE, "Kennedy Suites Single: $" + KENNEDY_SINGLE };

private String[] mealList = { "10 meals per week plus $200 flex dollars: $" + TEN_MEALS_200_FLEX,
                              "10 meals per week plus $350 flex dollars: $" + TEN_MEALS_350_FLEX,
                              "14 meals per week plus $400 flex dollars: $" + FOURTEEN_MEALS_400_FLEX };
```

I made these arrays into Combo Boxes. The all caps are my constants so I can change the price whenever I want.

```
private class ButtonLister implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int total = 0;
        String dormSelection = (String) dormsComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        String mealSelection = (String) mealsComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        total = 
        }
}
```

Would it make sense to tokenize with a delimiter of $ to get the price and add it to the total? Or might there be a way to identify which suite it is and use the constants to calculate the total?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily parse the money from a String as a number.

```
Number num = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse(str);
```

**Edit :** So to format your number, retrieve the string using `indexof`

```
Number num = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).parse(str.substring(str.indexOf("$")));
```